# .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted exactly the same functionality as in http://jsfiddle.net/8nqkA/2/ (coded by someone)

So, I tried something like in http://jsfiddle.net/c78oLbg2/4/

I am not understanding where is the mistake in my code.
May be there is something very trivial and I don't know as I am a newbie here:

```js
no_of_p = $('div#mydiv p').length;
for (i = 0; i < no_of_p; i++) {
    $('div#mydiv p:eq(i)').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div#mydiv p:eq(i)').fadeOut(1000);
};
```

```css
#mydiv p {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2 </p>
    <p>para 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is here `$('div#mydiv p:eq(i)')` the `i` is interpreted as a name not as a number index since you did not concatenate the i variable.

Comment: @andrex - That's not the only problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You variable is not interpreted in the string. If you want to add a variable value into the string, you need a string concatenation. Just like that :

```
$('div#mydiv p:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(1000);
$('div#mydiv p:eq('+i+')').fadeOut(1000);
```

But it would be easier to use function provided by jQuery like `.each`:

```
$('div#mydiv p').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

That answer why the fade is not working

---

Not to make a loop fade, you should make a recursive function that fade the first element and call itself with the same set of element minus the first one. That code does it :

```js
recursiveFade($('div#mydiv p'));

function recursiveFade($el){
    $el.first().fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        recursiveFade($el.slice(1));
    })
}
```

```css
#mydiv p {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>how are you </p>
    <p>bye</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixes a syntax but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @j08691 actually yeah, it answer is direct question *"JQuery .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() not working in for loop"* but did not take time to watch the first fiddle.

Comment: Soooo you plan on updating your answer?

Comment: @karl I like it the way you took the recursive +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the 'concatenation' as mentioned by you displays all at the same time. So, what to do to achieve this by using for loop only?

Comment: @ChiCha the recursition call is way better but if you really need to use the `for` loop, you can use `.delay` : http://jsfiddle.net/c78oLbg2/9/

Answer (score 2):

In your code i is consider as String and not int. Hence concat it

```
no_of_p = $('div#mydiv p').length;
for (i = 0; i < no_of_p; i++) {
    $('div#mydiv p:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div#mydiv p:eq('+i+')').fadeOut(1000);
};
```

Comment: That fixes a syntax error but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: it will display all in one time

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the 'concatenation' as mentioned by you displays all at the same time. So, what to do to achieve this by using for loop only?

Answer (score 2):

Use `callback` in fadeIn

```
var i = 0;

function myFunc() {
    $('div#mydiv p').eq(i).fadeIn(2000 , function() {;
    $('div#mydiv p').fadeOut();
               i++;
             myFunc();
     });

}

 myFunc();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c78oLbg2/5/)

Comment: So far this is the only answer that does what the OP is asking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.delay() to make them appear one after another.

Try this:

```
no_of_p = $('div#mydiv p').length;
for (i = 0; i < no_of_p; i++) {
    $('div#mydiv p:eq(' + i + ')').delay(i*2000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
};
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c78oLbg2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues to adress under your source code, such as the index `i` never change as it is part of the selector string.

But in order to have it work as the snippet you have shown, the call should be recursive and called within a callback function:

```js
    var i = 0;
    function fadeInOut(index) {
        var elt =$('div#mydiv p').eq(i);
        elt.fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(1000);
            fadeInOut(i++);
        });    
    }

    fadeInOut(i);
```

```css
#mydiv p {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>how are you </p>
    <p>bye</p>
</div>
```

*[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c78oLbg2/7/)*.